# Add a domain to another domain seems not work in nodejs

Tags: node.js, dns, eventemitter

in nodejs v11: below code not behave expectedly:

```
let domain = require('domain');
let d1 = domain.create();
let d2 = domain.create();

d1.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('caught by d1', err);   // not run in this case
});

d1.add(d2);
let f = d2.bind(() => {
  throw 'this is a test'
})

f();
```

And this is the actual result:

```
/test123.js:11
  throw 'this is a test'
  ^
this is a test
```

Surely the error function `f` threw is not routed to d1's error handler.
But according the Nodejs' document:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/domain.html#domain_domain_add_emitter

> Explicitly adds an emitter to the domain. If any event handlers called by the emitter throw an error, or if the emitter emits an 'error' event, it will be routed to the domain's 'error' event, just like with implicit binding.

As we run `d1.add(d2)`, then bind f to d2 and run f. Then d2 will emit an error event which should routed to d1's error handler because d2's own error handler is not defined yet.
And below demo meet my understanding:

```
let domain = require('domain');
let d1 = domain.create();
let d2 = domain.create();
d1.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('caught by d1', err);  //run in this case
});

d1.add(d2);
d2.emit('error', 123);
```

And output:
    node test123.js
    caught by d1 123

Apparently d1 caught the error event d2 emitted.
So my question is:
What make the difference between:
Why domain d1 cannot catch the error event d2 emitted which caused by a thrown error by a function bound to domain d2?